# Is it possible to disable the "mejs-time-float" element in mediaelement.js?

Tags: mediaelement.js

Is it possible to disable the "mejs-time-float" element (pictured here displaying 5:01), which appears above the MediaElement players on hover?

[image: "mejs-time-float" element, displayed]

Answer (score 2):

Simply hiding the span.mejs-time-float will not fix this issue, because it is already hidden by default and is shown (using jQuery .show()) when you mouse over span.mejs-time-total:

```
total = controls.find('.mejs-time-total')
```

...

```
total
.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
    // only handle left clicks
    if (e.which === 1) {
        mouseIsDown = true;
        handleMouseMove(e);
        $(document)
            .bind('mousemove.dur', function(e) {
                handleMouseMove(e);
            })
            .bind('mouseup.dur', function (e) {
                mouseIsDown = false;
                timefloat.hide();
                $(document).unbind('.dur');
            });
        return false;
    }
})
.bind('mouseenter', function(e) {
    mouseIsOver = true;
    $(document).bind('mousemove.dur', function(e) {
        handleMouseMove(e);
    });
    if (!mejs.MediaFeatures.hasTouch) {
        timefloat.show();
    }
})
.bind('mouseleave',function(e) {
    mouseIsOver = false;
    if (!mouseIsDown) {
        $(document).unbind('.dur');
        timefloat.hide();
    }
});
```

The quick and dirty option to actually disable the little tooltip functionality would be to delete the 'mouseenter' binding above or add the following directly following it:

```
total.unbind('mouseenter');
```

That will unbind the mouseenter event.

But that's kind of ugly, since you're modifying a library, and if you ever update the library all your changes will be wiped away. A better way to do it is to simply unbind after you initialize the MediaElement player:

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({ 
... your options ...
});

$('.mejs-time-total').unbind('mouseenter');
```

And now the little tooltip will not appear when you hover.

Answer (score 1):

MediaElement is skinable via CSS, so you just have to hide it in CSS.

```
.mejs-time-float{ 
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Don't believe this will fix anything. It is already hidden by default and is shown on mouseenter over span.mejs-time-total.

Answer (score 1):

Setting this to "display: none" does not help, but if you use "!important" in addition to that, seems to work just fine, since important will override the inline style added by jQuery:

```
.mejs-time-float {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unbinding mouseeenter worked for the hover issue, but in some browsers, we still saw the time float when we'd click the progress bar. I don't think this is ideal, but it works, since jQuery .show() doesn't touch visibility:

```
.mejs-time-float {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for Disable tooltip that shows time popup in progress bar:

```
$('video, audio').mediaelementplayer({

    enableProgressTooltip: false

});
```